# Безнаказанная травля новичков участниками с высокой репутацией

Tags: обсуждение

Сегодня я зашел на мету, чтобы почитать новые ответы и обсудить волнующие меня вопросы. И был очень неприятно удивлен.

Я заметил, что некий участник (не буду называть ник) с репутацией 140к+  позволяет себе меня оскорблять и совершенно никого не стесняется.

В связи с этим - я хотел бы уточнить. Могу ли я тоже оскорблять людей, мнение которых отличается от моего? Или такая опция доступна только после определенного уровня репутации?

Comment: Слева от коментов есть флажок специальный, надо пометить комментарий как оскорбляющий, тогда модеры увидят и разберутся

Comment: Я просто думал - возможно это норма

Comment: О том норма или нет не знаю, я сам новичок здесь

Comment: Имхо надо удалить упоминания репутации из текста и заголовка ибо они не имеют отношения к ситуации и уводят фокус в ненужное русло

Comment: Имеют непосредственное отношение

Comment: Какое? Окей, предположим, что высокорепам нельзя безнаказанно травить новичков. А наоборот? А среднячкам травить новичков/старичков? А среднячков травить старичкам/новичкам? Вопрос про травлю/оскорбления, репутация тут ни к селу ни к городу.

Comment: В законодательстве многих стран мира есть статьи за умышленную порчу информации (хотя эти законы часто противоречат конституциям этих же стран). За ваши ответы вас уже можно привлечь к ответственности.

Comment: С такой высокой репутацией людей не так много, поэтому дав информацию, о том что репутация 140к + вы открыли ник участника =)

Answer (score 12):

> Могу ли я тоже оскорблять людей, мнение которых
> отличается от моего? Или такая опция доступна только после
> определенного уровня репутации?

Нет, "не можете" и "ни с какого".

Подробнее тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct

На текущий момент указанные флаги обработаны.

Если вам кажется что вас провоцируют и троллят — возле комментария есть кнопка тревоги, можете нажимать.

Первая тревога была отклонена: в ней не навешивались ярлыки на людей, речь шла о некотором недостойном поведении. Негодование по поводу действий модсостава мы вообще стараемся оставлять в исходном виде, по крайней мере это защищает от упрёков "модераторы трут критику в свой адрес".

Вторая тревога была принята, там уже достаточно устойчиво навешивались оскорбительные ярлыки.

Обе тревоги были обработаны мной. В случае повторных тревог на первом комментарии я пропущу эту тревогу, выскажется кто-то другой из модсостава .

---

В частном порядке высказываю своё мнение как участника: ваше поведение в некоторых случаях можно оценить как провокацию и троллинг. Вероятно вам нравится, но в подавляющем большинстве у участников на сайте иные ценности — поэтому рано или позно вы переступите грань и будете забанены за нарушение правил. Оно вам надо?